# If $X$ is a random variable, then $X^{\pm}$ are random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

> For $x\in\mathbb{R}$, let $x^+:=\max\{0,x\}$ be its positive part, $x^-:=-\min\{0,x\}$ be its negative part. Prove that if $X$ is a random variable, then $X^{\pm}$ are random variables too.

I have attempted to prove this by using definition of a random variable, hence I tried to show $\forall t\in\mathbb{R}$, $\{X^+\le t\}$ and $\{X^-\le t\}$ are events. But somehow when I tried to evaluate them I got confused myself, especially when they are divided into cases for $x<0$ and $x\ge 0$ but $X^+$ and $X^-$ themselves are already its positive and negative part.

Here is how I wrote it:
$$\{X^+\le t\}= \begin {cases} ?&\text{if }x < 0;\\
?&\text{if }x \ge 0. \end {cases}$$
$$\{X^-\le t\}= \begin {cases} ?&\text{if }x < 0;\\
?&\text{if }x \ge 0. \end {cases}$$

Would anyone kindly help me to make this confusion clear? How can I complete the evaluation of $\{X^+\le t\}$ and $\{X^-\le t\}$?

Thanks.

Edit:

Thank you @user64480 for pointing out the mistake and providing the solution.

Here is the correct one:
$$\{X^+\le t\}= \begin {cases} \emptyset,&\text{if }t < 0;\\
\{X\le t\},&\text{if }t \ge 0. \end {cases}$$
$$\{X^-\le t\}= \begin {cases} \emptyset,&\text{if }t < 0;\\
\{X\ge -t\}&\text{if }t \ge 0. \end {cases}$$

Comment: Couldn't you just argue that $\text{max}\{0,.\}\circ X$ is a random variable because $\text{max}\{0,.\}$ is a function and $X$ is a random variable?

Comment: @Raskolnikov technically you would need the concept of a measurable function. I'm not sure what exactly their framework is, but it seems they're focusing on what it means to be an "event" instead.

Comment: @user64480: Indeed, a lot depends on the framework from which they can work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your cases should depend on whether $t$ is positive or negative. Remember, in the expression $\{X^+\le t\}$, we think of $t$ as fixed.

If $t< 0$, then $\{X^+\le t\}$ is empty since $X^+$ is nonnegative. The empty set is an event.

If $t\ge 0$, then $\{X^+\le t\}=\{X\le t\}$. This is because if $X^+\le t$, then $\max(0,X)\le t$, so in particular $X\le t$. Conversely, if $X\le t$, then, since we also assumed $0\le t$, it follows that $X^+=\max(0,X)\le t$.  Thus the two sets are indeed equal. But $\{X\le t\}$ is an event since $X$ is a random variable.

Try to do a similar analysis for $X^-$.

Comment: Thank you. your explanation was very clear. I have tried the $X^-$ case, $\{X^-\le t\}=\{-X\le t\}$. hopefully it is correct :)